# i cant resolve the error while scrolling images get replicated and image wont stay in the same position

Tags: android

this is the adapter class while scrolling the image it just goes off and on 
i have see many post regarding it but not a solution yet found to the above problem  resolve the error while scrolling images get replicated and image wont stay in the same position

```
    public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<ListItem> listData;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListItem> listData) {
    this.listData = listData;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.headlineView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.reporterNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.reporter);
        holder.reportedDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ListItem newsItem = listData.get(position);
    holder.headlineView.setText(newsItem.getHeadline());
    holder.reporterNameView.setText(" " + newsItem.getReporterName());
    holder.reportedDateView.setText(newsItem.getDate());

    if (holder.imageView != null) {
        new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(newsItem.getUrl());
    }

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView headlineView;
    TextView reporterNameView;
    TextView reportedDateView;
    ImageView imageView;
}
}
```

imagedownloadertask

```
    package imzzy.hearing_aid.com.hearingaid;

    /**
    * Created by imzzy on 10/29/2016.
    */

    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
    //import com.example.customizedlist.R;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.ImageView;


    class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

public ImageDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
    imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
    return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (isCancelled()) {
        bitmap = null;
    }

    if (imageViewReference != null) {
        ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
        if (imageView != null) {
            if (bitmap != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } else {
                Drawable placeholder = imageView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder);
                imageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
            }
        }

    }
}

private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL uri = new URL(url);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();

        int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            return null;
        }

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            return bitmap;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
        Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error downloading image from " + url);
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

string.xml

```
    <resources>
<string name="app_name">IYCC</string>

<string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
<string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

<!-- TODO: Remove or change this placeholder text -->
<string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hello blank fragment</string>

<array name="images_array">
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/images/IYCC.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/63.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/64.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/65.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/66.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/67.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/68.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/69.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/70.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/71.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/72.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/73.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/74.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/75.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/76.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/77.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/78.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/79.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/80.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/81.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/82.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/83.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/84.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/85.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/86.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/87.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/88.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/89.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/90.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/91.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/92.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/93.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/94.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/95.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/96.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/97.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/98.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/99.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/100.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/101.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/102.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/103.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/104.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/105.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/106.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/107.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/108.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/109.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/110.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/111.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/112.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/113.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/114.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/115.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/116.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/117.png</item>
    <item>http://imzzy.coolpage.biz/PhotoUpload/uploads/118.png</item>
</array>

<array name="headline_array">
    <item>image 1</item>
    <item>image 2</item>
    <item>image 3</item>
    <item>image 4</item>
    <item>image 5</item>
    <item>image 6</item>
    <item>image 7</item>
    <item>image 11</item>
    <item>image 21</item>
    <item>image 31</item>
    <item>image 41</item>
    <item>image 51</item>
    <item>image 61</item>
    <item>image 71</item>
    <item>image 11</item>
    <item>image 21</item>
    <item>image 31</item>
    <item>image 41</item>
    <item>image 51</item>
    <item>image 16</item>
    <item>image 71</item>
    <item>image 11</item>
    <item>image 21</item>
    <item>image 31</item>
    <item>image 41</item>
    <item>image 51</item>
    <item>image 61</item>
    <item>image 71</item>
    <item>image 72</item>
    <item>image 2</item>
    <item>image 3</item>
    <item>image 4</item>
    <item>image 5</item>
    <item>image 6</item>
    <item>image 7</item>
    <item>image 11</item>
    <item>image 21</item>
    <item>image 31</item>
    <item>image 41</item>
    <item>image 51</item>
    <item>image 61</item>
    <item>image 71</item>
    <item>image 11</item>
    <item>image 21</item>
    <item>image 31</item>
    <item>image 41</item>
    <item>image 51</item>
    <item>image 16</item>
    <item>image 71</item>
    <item>image 11</item>
    <item>image 21</item>
    <item>image 31</item>
    <item>image 41</item>
    <item>image 51</item>
    <item>image 61</item>
    <item>image 71</item>
    <item>image 72</item>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to load images using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). It nearly handles everything like Handling `ImageView` recycling and download cancelation in an adapter.

> Instead of

```
 new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(newsItem.getUrl());
```

> Use this

```
Picasso.with(context).load(newsItem.getUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(holder.imageView);
```

Declare a global variable for context and assign it in adapter's constructor.

Add In your project gradle,

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

---

The complete adapter code:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<ListItem> listData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListItem> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.headlineView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.reporterNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.reporter);
            holder.reportedDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ListItem newsItem = listData.get(position);
        holder.headlineView.setText(newsItem.getHeadline());
        holder.reporterNameView.setText(" " + newsItem.getReporterName());
        holder.reportedDateView.setText(newsItem.getDate());

        if (holder.imageView != null) {
            Picasso.with(context).load(newsItem.getUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(holder.imageView);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView headlineView;
        TextView reporterNameView;
        TextView reportedDateView;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: i am usuing string to fetch image cant use picasso

Comment: Can you share `ImageDownloaderTask` code and a sample url.

Comment: sure added imagedownalodertask and string.xml code which contains urls

Comment: I checked your code and Picasso will work perfectly with your code. Before   I hard-coded the URL by mistake... check my updated answer.

Comment: should i just replace it now

Comment: how to assign it in adapter constructor